# Applying a list of items to every view in views.py

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to apply a list of items to every view without having to do it manually for every view?
I have got a list of items in my navbar and I have to add this to every view to have it displayed in every page:

```
category_list = Category.objects.all()
context = {
    'category_list': category_list
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done through [*context processors* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors). These are functions that add items to the context each time a template is rendered. You can for example write such processor in a file named `app/context_processors.py` (with `app` the name of your app):

```
# app/context_processors.py

def category_list(request):
    return {
        'category_list': Category.objects.all()
    }
```

In the `settings.py` file, you then register the context processor:

```
# settings.py

# …

TEMPLATES = {
    # …,
    'OPTIONS': {
        # …,
        'context_processors': [
            # …,
            'app.context_processors.category_list'
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I get `Module "django.template.context_processors" does not define a "category_list" attribute/class` error

Comment: @Menor: but the name of your app is not `django.template` I guess? You should use the *name* of the app.